# MOD security project

Tags: web-applications, security

i am a student and i have to demo how mod security works in my class.
so far i have been able to download the module modsecurity-apache_2.5.12, i have a basic idea on how and what mod security is.i have seen Ivan ristic's videos.
the problem is...
i dont know how to edit the httpd.conf.in file.What changes to make and how.so far i am working on UBUNTU in virtualbox.can someone please help me out.let me know some links or some basic steps that will make my task easier.THANKS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an assignment, so I will not answer it for you directly.

The free docs are here (see installation step 4):

http://modsecurity.org/documentation/modsecurity-apache/2.5.12/modsecurity2-apache-reference.html

And a very nice book on it (also via PDF) from feistyduck.com (disclaimer: I get royalties on the book).

-B